# Blackberry QR code decoding prob in OS 6

Tags: blackberry, barcode-scanner, zxing

I am using the following code for 2D-QR code decoder.

```
package com.test.rim;

import java.util.*;

import net.rim.device.api.barcodelib.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;

import com.google.zxing.*;

final class BarcodeScanScreen extends MainScreen{

    BarcodeScanScreen barcodeScanScreen;

    BarcodeScanScreen(){

        BarcodeDecoderListener listener = new BarcodeDecoderListener(){

            public void barcodeDecoded( String rawText )
            {
                Dialog.alert(rawText);
            }
        };

        Hashtable hints = new Hashtable(1);
        Vector formats  = new Vector(1);
        formats.addElement(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
        hints.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, formats);

        BarcodeDecoder decoder = new BarcodeDecoder( hints );

        try{
            BarcodeScanner scanner = new BarcodeScanner( decoder, listener );
            scanner.getVideoControl().setDisplayFullScreen( true );
            add( scanner.getViewfinder() );
            scanner.startScan();
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Catch errors here
            Dialog.alert("Error:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

To start this screen, I am firing the a code `app.pushScreen(new BarcodeScanScreen());` on a button tap from its previous screen.

When I am running the code, the `BarcodeScanScreen` starts properly and the scanning is also going on(as the red light of the device is blinking). As soon as I place the cam before any valid 2D-QR code, the blink stops. I think it means, any barcode is decoded successfully and therefore the scanner stops. But `barcodeDecoded()` method is not fired as no alert massage is appear in the screen. What is the problem in my code?

Comment: Did you test the sample code which is provided by Blackberry samples? First test the BarcodeDemo which is provided by Blackberry Samples; You are not stop the scanning when it find the data in BarcodeListener;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code in `barcodeDecoded()` and it solves my prob.

```
app.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                      try { javax.microedition.media.Manager.playTone(ToneControl.C4, 1000, 100);} catch (MediaException e) { } 
                      app.popScreen(_barcodeScreen);
                      showDecoded(rawText);
                }
            });
            _barcodeScreen.invalidate();
```

Comment: Can also use:
app.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                      try { javax.microedition.media.Manager.playTone(ToneControl.C4, 1000, 100);} catch (MediaException e) { } 
                      app.popScreen(_barcodeScreen);
                      _barcodeScreen.invalidate();
                      showDecoded(rawText);
                }
            });

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine so the only thing I can think of is that `Dialog.alert` does not run successfully because your `BarcodeScanScreen` cannot display a modal dialog on top of it - the video preview window cannot have an overlay. Try stopping the scanner and popping the video preview screen off the stack before displaying your alert.

Comment: I try to make a sound by this code: try {                  javax.microedition.media.Manager.playTone(ToneControl.C4, 1000, 100);} catch (MediaException e) { }} But no sound.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point on `barcodeDecoded` and then running the debugger to see if it is actually called?

Comment: dev_android, Use **Alert.startAudio(new short[]{1046, 200}, 100);** to create the beep.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is You are not stop the scanning after getting the data in **BarcodeDecoderListener**;

First see the sample code provided by the blackberry sample name **BarcodeDemo**;

In your code, instead of Doing this:

```
BarcodeDecoderListener listener = new BarcodeDecoderListener()
{
    public void barcodeDecoded( String rawText )
    {
         Dialog.alert(rawText);
    }
};
```

Do like this:

```
BarcodeDecoderListener listener =new BarcodeDecoderListener() 
{
public void barcodeDecoded(String rawText) 
{
    try 
    {           
        barcodeScanner.stopScan();
         Dialog.alert(rawText);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        //Catch the Exception
    }                   
}
};
```